# Input at bottom row at python

Tags: python, input, console

how to make an input appear at the bottom of the terminal/console?

with

```py
import Console

a = Console.getconsole()
a.text(0,-1,'YOU CAN PRINT TEXT IN THE BOTTOM ROW OF CONSOLE')
```

you can print text in the bottom of the console, but you can't input. how can you make an input at the bottom of the console?

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gWv5.png)

[More detailed picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A9aW.png)

Im getting answers that are not what im searching exactly for but i understand them. Other option for me it would be have 2 consoles and whain i imput something in console1 smething happens to console2.

Comment: can u do a.input? or something?

Answer (score 0):

The console (or terminal) in python works in a way that it goes to the next available line. However, you can use the `get_terminal_size()` method to do complete the task.

What one could do is add many blank lines like this:

```py
import os

# Get the size of the terminal
size = os.get_terminal_size()

print('number of rows', size.lines)

a="\n"*(size.lines - 2)

name= input(a+'what is your name?')

print('hello', name)
```

which would look like this:

[image]

Comment: but i want to get console height then ignore rows  that alredy have a text and then maye just maybe repeat that num of times the \n but user can input more than one row

Comment: thank you for confirming.  Here is the complete solution....

Answer (score 0):

Functions or libraries are not available to fulfill the desired output then there is always a way to achieve the result by **logic.**

```
print('abc')
a="\n"*10

x= input(a+'Enter here :')

print(x)
```